# Implementing jquery datepicker using a template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement a jquery datepicker in my MVC 3 application. It works fine in edit mode, but when trying to use it in the create view, I get the null dictionary exception which tells me it cannot take a null value and needs a value of DateTime. Of course it's going to be null, your trying to create a new field. How can I get this to work.

Comment: Show us some code. When exactly did you get the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `EditorTemplate` instead of custom helper

Create new partial view Date.ascx and place it in `\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<%: Html.TextBox("", Model == null ? "" : ((DateTime)Model).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new { @class = "datepicker", @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

That works fine for all properties of type `DateTime`

Comment: This solution works. But I discovered that you don't even need a template. Just place your script in the _Layout.cshtml. The date fields for edit and create views are the same within they're specific controller. So I just did my datepicker script like this. $("#HireDate, #EnrollmentDate, #StartDate").datepicker();

Comment: But you don't have `#HireDate`, `#EnrollmentDate` on every page, so placing this script in _Layout.cshtml is not the best solution. Moreover, you have to remember that every time you add new view with date fields you have to modify this script.

Answer (score 0):

A lot easier using custom helper, im using helper below in one of my application.

1.Create Helper class

```
  namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
    {
        public static class DatePickerHelper
        {
            public static string DatePicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string id, string name, string value)
            {
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                sBuilder.AppendLine("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("$(function () {");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("$(\"#" + id + "\").datepicker({");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("showOn: \"button\",");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("buttonImage: \"/Content/images/icon-calendar.gif\",");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("buttonImageOnly: true");
                sBuilder.AppendLine(" });");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("});");
                sBuilder.AppendLine("</script>");

                sBuilder.AppendLine("<input type=\"text\" value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\""+name+"\" class=\"SmallTextBox\" />");
                return sBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

1. use it like this on your view (For creating)
   in my case i have Controller call Employee, make sure you use this pattern if you are using data model { "YouControllerName.PropertyName" and "YouControllerName_PropertyName"

   <%= Html.DatePicker("Employee_StartDate","Employee.StartDate","") %>
2. For editing

   <%=Html.DatePicker("Employee_StartDate","Employee.StartDate",Model.Employee.StartDate.ToShortDateString()) %>

Comment: I have no Idea what your talking about. I never read anything about using a stringbuilder for a datepicker helper. I am pretty new at this though, so.....